# Android, onReceive in BroadCastReceiver is being called multiple times

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've a question about the `AlarmManager` and the `BroadcastReceiver`!

I want to use the `AlarmManager` to update some data every 15th minute (this is not the case in the code since I'm still trying to get the functionality to work) but something I don't really understand has occurred.

Every time the `onReceive` method is being called by the timer, it gets called 3-5 fast times at once, the `LogCat` message is being written 3-5 times. Is it something wrong with my code?

Code:

Method in the `MainActivity` class:

```
private void setCloseByChecker() {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CloseByReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
            cal.getTimeInMillis() + 15000, 15000, pendingIntent);       
}
```

And the `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     

    Log.i("hello","hello");
}
```

Comment: time is expressed in milliseconds,  15000 ms are infact 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes i know, I use 15 seconds right now just to test it. But everytime the timer hits the onReceive method is being called 3-5 fast times.

Comment: I have this problem..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849474/alarm-expires-earlier-than-intended-when-using-setinexactrepeating

Comment: Maybe you're registering for that broadcast as several instances?

Comment: Try setting your alarm as follows, `onReceive` won't get called multiple times.

`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 15000, 15000, pendingIntent);`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation.

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

For testing purposes, change the `public void setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)` set intervalMillis to 5 minutes or something, then repeat the operation. Should you still receive more than one Broadcast, its something else.

Also, from the documentation:

> This alarm continues repeating until explicitly removed with cancel(PendingIntent).

Meaning that you should cancel the PendingIntent every time it completes what it needs to do, otherwise you may be using recursing to set an operation until you complete it. To check for this, run your code for a couple of minutes, then check if the BroadCast ammount has increased. If it did, you are starting a new alarm before the last one completed.

Then again, from the same documentation:

> If your application wants to allow the delivery times to drift in order to guarantee that at least a certain time interval always elapses between alarms, then the approach to take is to use one-time alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Are you canceling them somehow? 
Remember that everytime you call `setRepeating()` with different IDs (the second parameter) you'll duplicate your alarm.

Try canceling all of your alarms by calling `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)`.