# Alarm Expires earlier than intended when using setInexactRepeating

Tags: java, android, timer, android-alarms

1) [Sample](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) was used for repeating alarm.

2) [setInexactRepeating(60000,60000)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), first one expires happens at **20 to 30 secs**, rest ones expires in time i.e **60secs.**

3) setInexactRepeating(1000 * 60 * 25,1000 * 60 * 25), first one expires happens at **10 to 14 mins~**, rest ones expires in time i.e **25mins**.

4) Docs says "Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time".

Anyone experienced this before?using [setExact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)/[set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and restart the alarm works well and [setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) has problem too!