# Inexact AlarmManager.setRepeating problems

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I read in several articles that from API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact.
Does this mean, that every device running Android 4.4 is unable to excecute exact repeatings? Or can I simply avoid this on such devices by using android:targetSdkVersion="18" in my project.

I think I do not need the features of API 19, but anyway, is it a better way to use setExact and update the time everytime the alarm is called? In my App the user should set a time at which he will be notified every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean, that every device running Android 4.4 is unable to excecute exact repeatings?

It means that methods like `set()` and `setRepeating()` are now inexact by default if your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher. There is a `setExact()` that you can use for exact alarms, and it would be up to you to implement the repeating part yourself, by calling `setExact()` again as part of processing the work triggered by a previous `setExact()` call.

> Or can I simply avoid this on such devices by using android:targetSdkVersion="18" in my project.

Yes, you can avoid this. Eventually, though, something is going to force your hand to raise your `android:targetSdkVersion` to 19 or higher. That means that eventually, you will either need to adapt your app to inexact behavior or use `setExact()` as I describe above.

> is it a better way to use setExact and update the time everytime the alarm is called?

Since `setExact()` does not exist prior to API Level 19, you can only use this on newer devices. Once you set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to 19 or higher, you will need to start using `setExact()` on those newer devices, while still using `set()` or `setRepeating()` on older devices. I am not aware of any benefits for using `setExact()` while still having an `android:targetSdkVersion` below 19.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped a lot. So i will set the target to 18.

Comment: @CommonsWare do I need to cancel my previous setexact on the onReceive callback before call a next setExact?Onreceive called twice some times Ina fraction of seconds any reason?

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder: `setExact()` does not repeat -- it is a one-shot event. You only need to `cancel()` it if you do not want it anymore, such as replacing it with an updated time. I suggest that you use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see what scheduled events you have and determine if you are accidentally scheduling two for some reason.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok right.. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63401&q=setexact&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars  Saw your post here..I am doing"setExact()-in-a-loop" To achieve repeating kind of stuff here.. i have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849474/alarm-expires-earlier-than-intended-when-using-setinexactrepeating . So when i use  setExact on a loop,but i see onRecieve called twice for one schedule.

Comment: Oh lord I hate Android sometimes. Only after I had to create an exact, looping alarm across reboots did I realise how crazy that task is between alarm managers internal fragmentation, job schedulers, work managers, even Evernote's lib etc..